# How to automatically generate id in sequence in spring jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to make a one-to-many sequence as follows:

for example:

| category | sub category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

Data model:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE7Tm.png)

Java code/Mapping:

Category class

```
package br.com.bank.adapter.repository.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "category")
public class CategoryEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "update_at")
private LocalDateTime update;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<SubCategoryEntity> subCategoryEntity = new HashSet<>();

}
```

SubCategory class

```
package br.com.bank.adapter.repository.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "sub_category")
public class SubCategoryEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "update_at")
private LocalDateTime update;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
private CategoryEntity category;

}
```

With the code above, I'm getting the following result:

| category | sub category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

Comment: Alternatively, why bother with IDs in sub-category at all? It looks like a weak entity that does not need its own ID.

Comment: For subCategory,  no need to generate IDs

Comment: @Matheus Rodrigues de Souza have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following config to have your own sequence set up by JPA Vendor (ex Hibernate).

```
public class SubCategoryEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SequenceSubCategoryId")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SequenceSubCategoryId", sequenceName = "SUB_CATEGORY_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    ....
    }
```

This way the `id` would be retrieved from the same sequence created in database and will always be increased by 1 in every new request.

This would work if you have set up the property

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` with one of the following values `create`, `create-drop`, `update` so that hibernate is allowed to create this sequence  in the schema automatically for you.

If you don't have this property configured this way you also need to execute the DDL script in your database to create the sequence named `SUB_CATEGORY_SEQ`